# pseudoelement disappears on chrome mobile and works fine on desktop

Tags: css

I am making a connect4 game that works fine on desktop but on chrome mobile the pseudoelements doesn't appear which is the circles in the game.

```
.circle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
}

:is(.circle.red, .circle.blue)::before {
  transition: 0.3s transform ease-in;
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
}

.circle.red::before {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.circle.blue::before {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: have you made sure `.circle::before` has `display: block` or `display: inline-block`? by default, it's `inline`, which doesn't support widths so that may be why it appears invisible

Comment: Browser compatibility? Check caniuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in :is operator is not supported in chrome mobile